# How to compute the integral over these regions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Define $B(0,r)=\{u=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\colon|u|\le r^2\}$ for $r>0$.

Let $R\subset B(0,2)$ be the region such that $|u|\le 4$ and $x\le\sqrt 3$. Let $S\subset B(0,2)$ be the region with $|u|\le 4$ and $x\le\sqrt 3$ and $z\le\sqrt 3$.

How can I compute the volume of $R$ and the Volume of $S$? I don't know how to determine the bounds of the integral.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (1) this problem has stood unanswered for over ten years; (2) it is not a particularly interesting or difficult problem, so (3) an answer to it will not significantly enhance the MSE archive; and (4) there is an error in the specification [the poser presumably meant "$ |u| \ \le \ r \ $" for $ \ B(0,r) \ \  ] \ . $